# How to add a description to Widgets?

Tags: widgets

The codex doesn't seem to say how one would go about adding a description to a custom widget registered with `wp_register_sidebar_widget()`. The default description seems to be the name of teh widget itself.

```
function myFunc(){
  /* widget code */
}
wp_register_sidebar_widget( 'wdgt1', 'Site Map', 'myFunc', array() );
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what you looking for:

```
class WP_Widget_Sitemap extends WP_Widget {

    function WP_Widget_Sitemap() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'widget_sitemap', 'description' => __( "This is the description" ) );
        $this->WP_Widget( 'sitemap', __('Site Map'), $widget_ops);
    }

    function widget() { ... }
    function form() { ... }
    function update() { ... }
...
```

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Developing_Widgets

Answer (score 3):

This is the old (and difficult) way to create WordPress widgets. Use the Widget API instead: http://codex.wordpress.org/Widget_API.

Answer (score -1):

it give a param for description in array of the function to register widget:

```
register_sidebar()
```

Example can you see on [this post](http://wpengineer.com/1871/wordpress-widget-areas-with-description/) or this code.

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'My Lorem Ipsum Sidebar',
        'description' => __('Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.', 'your_textdomain'),
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</li>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));
}
```

Comment: You are adding a new sidebar, I think Jonathan wants to add a new sidebar widget.

Comment: you have right, sorry. the param is also the same.